# Правильно ли я работаю с массивом Json?

Tags: android, json

Я получаю с сервера массив данных в формате Json. Вот как я его вытаскиваю из ответа сервера:

```
JsonArray filter1 = response.body().getFilters().getAsJsonArray("prof");
```

дальше вот что я получаю в логах если выведу переменную `filter1`:

```
[{"count":1,"name":"name1","id":13392},{"count":2,"name":"name2","id":13408},{"count":3,"name":"name3","id":13466}]
```

дальше мне нужно получить каждую переменную по отдельности и я пишу такие строки:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filter1.size(); i++) {
JsonElement object = filter1.get(i);
Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(object));
}
```

в логах я получаю такое:

```
{"count":1,"name":"name1","id":13392}
{"count":2,"name":"name2","id":13408}
{"count":3,"name":"name3","id":13466}
```

вроде бы как получаю каждую переменную по отдельности и это то что нужно. Дальше я планирую перенести все в массив и тд. Но вот возник вопрос - правильно ли я сделал? Буду благодарен за критику и полезные советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавьте Gson в Gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Добавьте класс-описание:

```
class Item{
    int count;
    String name;
    int id;
}
```

Пример:

```
String jsonOutput = "[{\"count\":1,\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":13392},{\"count\":2,\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":13408},{\"count\":3,\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":13466}]";

Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>(){}.getType();

List<Item> items = new Gson().fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);

for (Item item : items){
    Log.i("Log",item.name);
}
```

Если вы получаете данные через retrofit2, то будет еще проще см.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029755/10965132

Comment: я то получаю все через retrofit2 но эти данные находятся в ответе на запрос,  и отдельно я их получить никак не могу кроме как вытаскиванием из json.

Comment: Так retrofit2 и заточен на то, что-бы в принимаемом ответе сразу преобразовывать json в объект (как я приводил выше, но в автоматическом режиме). в onResponse можно получить уже готовый класс (список классов). Вот тут хороший мануал: https://habr.com/ru/post/428736/

Comment: у меня как-раз все так как вы и пишите)) в чем суть - у меня есть список вакансий который я загружаю с сайта. У меня есть апи для которого есть интерфейс в котором я прописал запрос, у меня есть модель вакансии, и главный класс-модель в котором есть массив моделей вакансий, и так же есть эти данные которые я в этом вопросе пытаюсь вытащить, я могу из ответа вытащить только json и все

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы в onResponse получаете "главный класс-модель" в котором есть свойство (строка) - массив моделей. Если это так - то может просто "главный класс-модель" дополнить свойством List<Items> items; ? Тогда вы можете сделать так: for (Item item : main.items)

Comment: сейчас если честно не очень понял, я на текущий момент в главном классе прописал строки - public JsonObject getFilters()  и так я получаю объект в формате json. Я не очень понимаю как можно через list вытащить три разных вида списков.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88947/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-virex-84).